# MFMessgecomposer user should not able to edit message and phonenumber

Tags: ios, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send the Messages. Is there any possibility making set recipients and set body fixed means,userintraction to those message and phone number should be NO?

If is not there any possibility to send message without showing this viewController.

As I googled it & didn’t find any solution

```
        messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        messageController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem.title = @"Cancel";
        [messageController setRecipients:recipents];
        [messageController setBody:self.message];

        [self presentModalViewController:messageController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Its not possible as Its redircted to  naive iOS messanger app, which  you  can  not control from ios app development, You can  just  set phone number and text msg.

Comment: thanks for reply. is there any other way with out using MFMessagecomposer

Comment: you can via any third party API or your own API written in php,java or dotnet.

Comment: k, let me know Any third party API